# Backbone saving only changed models in a collection with changed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

If I have a collection of models, and then inside my code I do:

```
collection[0].set({name: "Joe"});
collection[1].set({username: "abcd"});
collection[10].set({name: "bob"});
```

Is there a way I can do a `.save()` on all the models, but have it update ONLY the fields and models that has been changed? As if the collection contains 1000+ models, doing a `fetch` the first time already takes up a lot of system resources, and doing a `.save()` for 1000+ models will take up even more...

Comment: does `collection[0]` even work..? because collection is an object and the models are inside a `models` property.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save):

> If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call model.save(attrs, {patch: true}).

Instead of doing `set()` on the attributes and then saving, call model.save and pass the set of attr

Comment: Yup, but I don't want to have to do it for each model that I changed. Is there a way to make backbone detect what model is changed and only do a `save()` on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the collection, check whether the model has changed using [`hasChanged()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged) and send a `PATCH` (or play with [`Sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to alter that) request for the changed ones. You can detect the changed attributes using [`changedAttributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes)

Pseudo-code :

```js
collection.each(function(model){
  if(model.hasChanged())
    model.save(attrs, {patch: true});
//---------------^ could be a single attribute, changes attributes or whatever
});
```

Side note: You shouldn't have 1000 models at a time then... there are techniques like pagination, lazy loading etc